# I want to know the exact meaning of 'Yet' in interrogative sentences

Tags: meaning

Honey, are you up yet?

In this sentence, the exact meaning of the word "yet" in an interrogative sentence is surprisingly already?
Does 'Yet' convey that the speaker didn't expect her husband to get up now, but surprisingly, he is already up?

Comment: Just the opposite: it implies that he's supposed to be up now but she fears he isn't.

Comment: Honey, are you still not up?

Comment: Thanks!! I have one more question about that. Then, how different is it from "aren't you up yet?" when a positive interrogative containing "yet" already has a negative impression akin to a negative interrogative?

Answer (score 1):

It means *have you completed X* or *have you finished X* (or *is X ready?*) where X is something taking multiple steps, dependent on some condition, or consumes a duration of time.

> Did you find the missing book yet?

*Getting up* can mean *to awaken and get out of bed* - you can be awake and still lying in bed, which would mean you have yet to fully get up.